# How to use recursive type in Kotlin

Tags: types, functional-programming, kotlin

What I want to do is something like this

```
fun <F, A, R> recur(f: (F, A) -> R, arg: A): R = f(f, arg)
where F = (F, A) -> R
```

How can I type this function in Kotlin?

Comment: Interesting. Can you give an example of how this function is used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define it as

```
fun <F : (F, A) -> R, A, R> recur(f: F, arg: A): R = f(f, arg)
```

However, I don't see any satisfying type system way how it can be invoked.